# Summarize data using doBy package at region level

Tags: r

I have a dataset Data as below,

```
Region  Country Market  Price     
EUROPE  France  France  30.4502    
EUROPE  Israel  Israel  5.14110965    
EUROPE  France  France  8.99665    
APAC    CHINA   CHINA   2.6877232    
APAC    INDIA   INDIA   60.9004    
AFME    SL      SL      54.1729685    
LA      BRAZIL  BRAZIL  56.8606917    
EUROPE  RUSSIA  RUSSIA  11.6843732    
APAC    BURMA   BURMA   63.5881232    
AFME    SA      SA      115.0733685
```

I would like to summarize the data at Region level and get the SUM of Price at every Region Level.

I want the ouput to be Like below.

```
Data Output


Region  Country Price     
EUROPE  France  30.4502    
EUROPE  Israel  5.14110965    
EUROPE  France  8.99665    
EUROPE  RUSSIA  11.6843732          
Europe          56.27233285         
APAC    BURMA   63.5881232    
APAC    CHINA   2.6877232    
APAC    INDIA   60.9004         
Apac            127.1762464         
AFME    BAHARAIN 54.1729685    
AFME    SA       115.0733685    
AFME             169.246337         
LA     BRAZIL    56.8606917         
LA               56.8606917
```

I have used summaryBy function of doBy package, i have tried the code below.

```
summaryBy

myfun1 <- function(x){c(s=Sum(x)}
DB= summaryBy(Data$Price ~Region + Country , data=Data, FUN=myfun1)
```

Anyhelp on this regard is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `dplyr` to generate a summary table:

```
library(dplyr)
totals <- data %>% group_by(Region) %>% summarise(Country="",Price=sum(Price))
```

And then merging the summary with the rest of the data:

```
summary <- rbind(data[-3], totals)
```

Then you can sort by Region to put the summary with the region:

```
summary <- summary %>% arrange(Region)
```

Output:

```
   Region Country    Price
1    AFME      SL  54.1730
2    AFME      SA 115.0734
3    AFME         169.2463
4    APAC   CHINA   2.6877
5    APAC   INDIA  60.9004
6    APAC   BURMA  63.5881
7    APAC         127.1762
8  EUROPE  France  30.4502
9  EUROPE  Israel   5.1411
10 EUROPE  France   8.9967
11 EUROPE  RUSSIA  11.6844
12 EUROPE          56.2723
13     LA  BRAZIL  56.8607
14     LA          56.8607
```

Comment: You probably could pipe the whole thing together as in `Data %>% 
  group_by(Region) %>% 
  summarise(Country="",Price=sum(Price)) %>%
  rbind(Data[-3]) %>%
  arrange(Region, desc(Country))`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion David. I tried both the methods but the total summary at regional level I am getting NA.. Eg. for AFME instead of 169.246 but the end result show AFME "NA".

Comment: The code seems to work on the data you've provided (using `read.table`). Could you add the structure of your data to your question by pasting the output of `dput(yourdata)`? If there's a lot of rows you can use `dput(head(data))`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split data by Region factor and sum Price for each factor

```
lapply(split(data, data$Region), function(x) sum(x$Price))
```

Or, if you need to present result as you have shown:

```
totals = lapply(split(data, data$Region), function(x) rbind(x,data.frame(Region=unique(x$Region), Country="", Market="", Price=sum(x$Price))))
do.call(rbind, totals)
```